# How do I make WebStorm recognize the JavaScript "window" object for type-hinting and warnings?

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

I'm working in React, running WebStorm 2017.3.5

WebStorm is not recognizing the window object as anything special like it does in other JavaScript projects.

For instance, both of the following lines produce *"Unresolved function or method"* warnings:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
window.alert("foo");
```

These (and other standard window methods) also don't show up in the code completion section when I type `window.`

The behavior works as expected for `document`.

Anyone know what I need to enable to make Web Storm aware of window?

EDIT: invalidating cache did not help.

Comment: try to `Ctrl+click` on `window` - what definition is opened? Also, what libraries are enabled in **File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**? What **JavaScript language version** is being used?

Comment: @lena I'm not able to ctrl-click on window, as it is not being recognized (see answer below), but I remember it offering to import the object, so it wasn't being recognized at something available. As for the language version, this occurred when using React/JSX

Comment: do you have **HTML** library enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**?

Answer (score 1):

Possible fix:

1. Change language level from React to ECMA 6 (Settings --> Languages & Frameworks --> JavaScript --> JavaScript language version
2. Delete all code in the current file (cut to clipboard)
3. type `window.` on the now empty first line. Type hinting should pick up on window, make it a different color, and show methods for alert(), addEventListener(), etc
4. Paste original code
5. Return language level to React/JSX

I have no idea why the above worked when invalidating caches and restarting did not. I tried doing just 2 and 3 alone without success, and just 1 alone also without success.